# Query a JSON column with an array of object in MySQL 2024

Tags: mysql, mysql-json

I have a json column with the follow array:

`[ { "name": "someone", "email": "someone@gmail.com", "passwdHash": "123" }, { "name": "sometwo", "email": "sometwo@gmail.com", "passwdHash": "456" } ]`

I tried the follow query to get the row that has the email "someone@gmail.com" in the "accounts" column, but it returns both "passwdHash":

`SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(accounts, '$[*].passwdHash') AS passwdHash FROM serverConfig WHERE json_contains(accounts->'$[*].email', json_array("someone@gmail.com"));`

Anyone know how to do the right query?

To get the right JSON MySQL query

Comment: You need to convert the array to multiple rows (one per element/object) first; https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-table-functions.html